# What is the proper way to get the input from Backoffice console in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to get the input from a text box from the backoffice console.What is the proper way to get the input?

I tried following the link:

https://hybrisdiary.com/2018/10/15/backoffice-customization/

```
   public class MyCustomInputController extends DefaultWidgetController
    {

private Textbox textInput;

@Override
public void initialize(final Component comp)
{
    super.initialize(comp);
}



@ViewEvent(componentID = "submitButton", eventName = Events.ON_CLICK)
public void doOperation()
{
    textInput.getText()
          //This is throwing a Null Pointer Exception
    }
   }
```

Expected result : Getting input from the following field:

```
  <textbox id="textInput"/>
```

Actual result : Null pointer rexception

Answer (score 1):

Individual back-office elements must be declared with `@Wire` annotation.

```
@Wire
private Textbox textInput;
```